# How to select all rows except (A and B) in Eloquent ORM using Scope?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to get all rows except few (A and B) in Eloquent ORM modal.

**User Model**

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('notification','listener_id','id');
}
```

**Model Notification**

```
public function scopeFriendship($query)
{
    return $query->where('object_type', '=', 'Friendship Request');
}

public function scopeSent($query)
{
    return $query->where('verb', '=', 'sent');
}
```

Here how can I get all notifications of a user except other than (Friendship and Sent) scope.

```
Something like:- all rows except !(Friendship AND Sent)
```

Comment: ur missing a quote there

Comment: I didn't really read the Q before.. now looking at it, I kinda doubt it is possible. You'll have to make a new scope for this operation.

Comment: something like this?  
`$notifications= $user->notifications()->whereNotIn('id',
Notification::where('listener_id',$user_id)->where('verb','=','sent')
->where('object_display_name', '=', 'Friendship Request')->select('id')->get()->toArray())
->get();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use scopes in combination with eager loading. Like that:

```
User::with(['notifications' => function($q){
    $q->friendship();
}])->get();
```

However we now need to invert the scope somehow. I can think of two ways to solve this.

#### 1. Add negative scopes

```
public function scopeNotFriendship($query){
    return $query->where('object_type', '!=', 'Friendship Request');
}

public function scopeNotSent($query){
    return $query->where('verb', '!=', 'sent');
}

User::with(['notifications' => function($q){
    $q->notFriendship();
    $q->notSent();
}])->get();
```

#### 2. Optional parameter

Or you could introduce an optional parameter to your current scopes. Something like this:

```
public function scopeFriendship($query, $is = true)
{
    return $query->where('object_type', ($is ? '=' : '!='), 'Friendship Request');
}

public function scopeSent($query, $is = true)
{
    return $query->where('verb', ($is ? '=' : '!='), 'sent');
}
```

This way you would only have to pass in false:

```
User::with(['notifications' => function($q){
    $q->friendship(false);
    $q->sent(false);
}])->get();
```

#### Edit

You can even gain more control by adding a second parameter for the `boolean` (`AND` or `OR` of the where:

```
public function scopeFriendship($query, $is = true, $boolean = 'and')
{
    return $query->where('object_type', ($is ? '=' : '!='), 'Friendship Request', $boolean);
}
```

And if you wanted either scope to be true:

```
$q->friendship(true, 'or');
$q->sent(true, 'or');
```

#### 2nd Edit

This one finally worked (from the chat)

```
Notification::where('listener_id', $user_id) 
    ->where(function($q){ 
        $q->friendship(false) 
        $q->sent(false, 'or') 
    }) 
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time to my problem. Btw I wanna follow your *2. Optional parameter*. But friendship and sent both will individually be true,but in combined it will be false.  
Something like this:-
!(Friendship_is_true AND Sent_is_true)`

Comment: Yes if you call it with `true` you can't combine them as it is. However there is a way to do this too.. Give me a minute I'll update my answer

Comment: But How can I get overall False..I means:- 
 `Not(Friendship_true AND Sent_True)`. Something link NAND operation.

Comment: That would be the code I posted first `$q->friendship(false); $q->sent(false);`. Does that not work?

Comment: I wanna make this query using scope  
`select * from notifications
minus
(select * from notifications where object_type='friendship_request' and verb='sent');`
Is it possible?

Comment: `Notifications::friendship(false)->sent(false)->get()`. Can you please try it and tell me if it works (and you want to know why) or if it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68566/discussion-between-bit-hunter-and-lukasgeiter).